# 405 when POST to change logging level using actuator in spring boot 2.2/4.*

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging, spring-boot-actuator

We have a spring boot app using spring boot 2.2.7. Saw from spring boot's documentation that the logging level of loggers can be dynamically changed using actuator endpoints, https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/actuator-api/htmlsingle/#loggers

this is my pom,

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

and as suggested, in my application.properties

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=loggers
management.endpoint.loggers.enabled=true
management.endpoint.loggers.post.enabled=true
```

then I make a GET to the actuator loggers endpoint that works fine

```
curl -ik  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' http://localhost:8080/actuator/loggers/org.springframework
HTTP/2 200
date: Fri, 01 Apr 2022 15:46:34 GMT
content-type: application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v3+json
content-disposition: inline;filename=f.txt
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
cache-control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
pragma: no-cache
expires: 0
strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains
x-frame-options: DENY

{"configured_level":"INFO","effective_level":"INFO"}
```

but when I POST, I got 405,

```
curl -i -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"configuredLevel": "debug"}' http://localhost:8080/actuator/loggers/org.springframework
HTTP/2 405
date: Fri, 01 Apr 2022 15:47:01 GMT
content-type: text/html;charset=utf-8
content-length: 449
set-cookie: JSESSIONID=4435480C10E16A53F466C51EC95DFF80; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
cache-control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
pragma: no-cache
expires: 0
strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains
x-frame-options: DENY
allow: GET
content-language: en

<!doctype html><html lang="en"><head><title>HTTP Status 405 – Method Not Allowed</title><style type="text/css">body {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;} h1, h2, h3, b {color:white;background-color:#525D76;} h1 {font-size:22px;} h2 {font-size:16px;} h3 {font-size:14px;} p {font-size:12px;} a {color:black;} .line {height:1px;background-color:#525D76;border:none;}</style></head><body><h1>HTTP Status 405 – Method Not Allowed</h1></body></html>
```

I have been looking around to get tricks, changing spring boot version to 2.4.0. None works. Can someone please shed some light into this? Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

we have
spring-boot-starter-security
and
spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client

to use oauth 2 to protect most endpoints.

Even though I have configured spring security with

```
http.
                .authorizeRequests(a -> a
                .antMatchers("/actuator/**").permitAll()
                ....
```

to allow actuator endpoints to go through, it is only good for GET.

I need to add

```
http.csrf().ignoringAntMatchers("/actuator/loggers/**").and()
                .authorizeRequests(a -> a
                .antMatchers("/actuator/**").permitAll()
......
```

to allow POST. Once I added the above line, I can POST to
/actuator/loggers/**
to change logging level